# looping api calls - slow performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an API call in a loop which takes ages to finish, but if i have a short delay in the loop it completes faster, which seems odd to me.

takes alot longer than the one below.

```
var questionsLength = questions.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < questionsLength; i++) {
  $scope.removeAll(questions[i]);
}
```

faster performance than above.

```
var questionIndex = 0;
(function loop (i) {
  if (questionIndex === 0) {
    timeoutcount = 0;
  } else { 
    timeoutcount = 3000;
    }

  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.removeAll(questions[questionIndex]);
    questionIndex++;
    if (--i) {          
      loop(i);       
    }
  }, timeoutcount);
})(questions.length);
```

what would be the appropriate way to handle several API calls?

Comment: try using a promise https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: IMO - a better way to handle this would be to have the API itself handle a bulk remove call, not having to call individual removes in a loop. This is general not a great way to do this unless you are really stuck with this api. This type of pattern tends to hinder front end performance quite a bit.